# Perform "javascript/jQuery-like" functions using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to move some processing from client to server side.

I am doing this via AJAX.

In this case `t` is a URL like this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/real-crime-profile/id1081244497?mt=2&uo=2.

First problem, I need to send a bunch of these URLs through this little function, to just pull out "1081244497" using my example. The following accomplishes this in javascript, but not sure how to make it loop in PHP.

```
    var e = t.match(/id(\d+)/);
      if (e) {
           podcastid= e[1];

      } else {
           podcastid = t.match(/\d+/);

      }
```

The next part is trickier. I can pass one of these `podcastid` at a time into AJAX and get back what I need, like so:

```
 $.ajax({
          url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup',
          data: {
              id: podcastid,
              entity: 'podcast'
          },
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          timeout: 5000,
          success: function(data) {
             console.log(data.results); 
          },  
      });
```

What I don't know how to do is accomplish this same thing in PHP, but also using the list of `podcastid`s without passing one at a time (but that might be the only way).

Thoughts on how to get started here?

**MAJOR EDIT**

Okay...let me clarify what I need now given some of the comments.

I have this in PHP:

```
 $sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $jObj = json_decode($json);
    $new = new stdClass();  // create a new object
    foreach( $sxml->entry as $entry ) {
        $t = new stdClass();
        $t->id      = $entry->id;
        $new->entries[] = $t;   // create an array of objects
    }
    $newJsonString = json_encode($new);
var_dump($new);
```

This gives me:

```
object(stdClass)#27 (1) {
  ["entries"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#31 (1) {
      ["id"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#32 (1) {
        [0]=>
        string(64) "https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/serial/id917918570?mt=2&uo=2"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#30 (1) {
      ["id"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#34 (1) {
        [0]=>
        string(77) "https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/real-crime-profile/id1081244497?mt=2&uo=2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I need now is to pull out each of the strings (the URLs) and then run them through a function like the following to just end up with this: "917918570,1081244497", which is just a piece of the URL, joined by a commas.

I have this function to get the id number for one at a time, but struggling with how the `foreach` would work (plus I know there has to be a better way to do this function):

```
$t="https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/real-crime-profile/id1081244497?mt=2&amp;uo=2";
$some =(parse_url($t));
$newsome = ($some['path']);
$bomb = explode("/", $newsome);
$newb = ($bomb[4]);
$mrbill = (str_replace("id","",$newb,$i));
print_r($mrbill);
//outputs 1081244497
```

Comment: @MarcB That's going to take a while for me to go through, but I will. What about the first part for pulling out the ids?

Comment: Your questions basically amount to: (1) How do I use regular expressions in PHP?  (2) How do I make HTTP requests in PHP?  (3) Does the iTunes API have a bulk query lookup?

Comment: parse_url, I'm guessing?

Comment: @David Well, that's quite a bit more succinct than what I have, but I think that's basically it. I do know about regex, but not quite sure on the looping to hit all the URLs I have and store them in a variable.

Comment: @jonmrich: What have you tried?  If you have an array of URLs, wouldn't you store the parsed identifiers in an array of strings?  Are you asking how arrays work?  How loops work?  It's really not clear where you're actually stuck here.

Comment: @David I just made a major update to my post if you can take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcB Tried out `parse_url` and was able to get something sort of working. I updated my question with a lot more information about where I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find match `preg_match()` and `http_build_query()` to turn array into query string. And `file_get_contents()` for the request of the data. and `json_decode()` to parse the json responce into php array.

in the end it should look like this.

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?'.http_build_query(['id'=>25,'entity'=>'podcast'])));
if(preg_match("/id(\d+)/", $string,$matches)){
    $matches[0];
}
```

You may have to mess with this a little. This should get you on the right track though. If you have problems you can always use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to debug.

As far as the Apple API use `,` to seperate ids

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253,284910350

you will get multiple results that come back into an array and you can use a `foreach()` loop to parse them out.

## **EDIT**

Here is a full example that gets the artist name from a list of urls

```
$urls = [
    'https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/real-crime-profile/id1081244497?mt=2&uo=2.',
    'https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/dan-carlins-hardcore-history/id173001861?mt=2'
];
$podcast_ids = [];
$info = [];
foreach ($urls as $string) {
    if (preg_match('/id(\d+)/', $string, $match)) {
        $podcast_ids[] = $match[1];
    }
}
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?' . http_build_query(['id' => implode(',', $podcast_ids)])));
foreach ($json_array->results as $item) {
    $info[] = $item->artistName;
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($info);
print '</pre>';
```

## **EDIT 2**

To put your object into an array just run it through this

```
foreach ($sxml->entries as $entry) {
    $urls[] = $entry->id[0];
}
```

When you access and object you use `->` when you access an array you use `[]`. Json and xml will parse out in to a combination of both objects and arrays. So you just need to follow the object's path and put the right keys in the right places to unlock that gate.

Comment: This is really helpful, especially the syntax for the Apple API. I just did a major update to my question, can you take another look?

Comment: @jonmrich I edited my answer, that is how you get the artist name

Comment: This EDIT is perfect. The challenge is that I'm pulling the URLs dynamically (in the same PHP file) and there could be up to 100 of them. Is there a way to dynamically create an object I can pass into this without making 100 `$ulrs[]` lines (which I'm not even sure could be done)?

Comment: all it needs it an array. how are you storing the data? Just do a foreach loop and add them to an array. One moment while I demo it

Comment: If I do 
`'$sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);`
`var_dump($sxml->entry->id);`
This gives me:
`object(SimpleXMLElement)#307 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(64) "https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/serial/id917918570?mt=2&uo=2"
}
`
This is the first id from the entire list of 100, so this is what I'd need to iterate.

Comment: Your EDIT 2, gives me this 100 times(1 for each returned object as expected):` [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) {
  }`

Comment: @jonmrich tweak the way you access the file. if it is an object use `->` else if it is an array use `[]` every time you go a layer deeper into your code, `var_dump` and check what you need to grab next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103230/discussion-between-neoaptt-and-jonmrich).